# When using emacs lisp, if the value exceed most-negative-number

Tags: emacs, elisp, x86-64

So, if I multiply two values:
emacs -batch -eval '(print (* 1252463 -4400000000000))'
It will exceed most-negative-fixnum frame and will return mathematically wrong answer. What will be the difference in instruction level between
-O2 flag, -O2 -fsanitize=undefined flag, and -O2 -fwrapv flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In emacs? Probably nothing. The function that is compiled probably looks like this:

```
int multiply(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

If we compile that and look at the assembly (`gcc -S multiply.c && cat multiply.s`), we get

```
multiply:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    imull   -8(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

See the `imull` instruction? It's doing a regular multiply. What if we try `gcc -O2 -S multiply.c`?

```
multiply:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax
    ret
```

Well that's certainly removed some code, but it's still doing `imull`, a regular multiplication.

Let's try to get it to not use `imull`:

```
int multiply(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

With `gcc -O2 -S multiply.c`, we get

```
multiply:
    leal    (%rdi,%rdi), %eax
    ret
```

Instead of computing the slower `x * 2`, it instead computed `x + x`, because addition is faster than multiplication.

Can we get `-fwrapv` to do produce different code? Yes:

```
int multiply(int x) {
    return x * 2 < 0;
}
```

With `gcc -O2 -S multiply.c`, we get

```
multiply:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    ret
```

So it was simplified into `x >> 31`, which is the same thing as `x < 0`. In math, if `x * 2 < 0` then `x < 0`. But in the reality of processors, if `x * 2` overflows it may become negative, for example `2,000,000,000 * 2 = -294967296`.

If you force gcc to take this into account with `gcc -O2 -fwrapv -S temp.c`, we get

```
multiply:
    leal    (%rdi,%rdi), %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    ret
```

So it optimized `x * 2 < 0` to `x + x < 0`. It might seem strange to have `-fwrapv` not be the default, but C was created before it was standard for multiplication to overflow in this predictable manner.

Comment: Do you know what happens if -fsanitize=undefined flag is used? Because it is throwing up external function __ubsan_handle_overflow which is not defined and will not execute.

Comment: Sounds like you installed clang wrong, `-fsanitize=undefined` works fine for me. Try reinstalling?

It should print out an error message, like `multiply.c:3:14: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2000000000 * 2 cannot be represented in type 'int'`. I highly doubt emacs will run properly if you compile it with `-fsanitize=undefined`, people rely on undefined behavior all the time.